Help needed with .htaccess
I have a website which needs to be changed from Nginx to Apache webserver.
The index directory is nl.html but the HTML extension is removed from the address bar.
If I visit the website example.com it shows in the address bar the following URL: example.com/nl but actually it's nl.html.
At the moment I have the following .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]

When I visit the website the root URL is shown without the /nl.
If I visit /nl/blog it shows a 404 but it should show /nl/blog.html the issue also appears on other files.
What am I missing here?

Your rewrite rule strips the uri that end in .html.  Then example.com/nl.html becomes example.com/nl and example.com/nl/blog.html becomes example.com/nl/blog. But the path /nl/blog.html doesn't exists in your server (the real path is /nl.html/blog.html), that's why you get a 404. I would advice to not name directories as dot extension: i.e. betternl_html instead of nl.html to avoid confusion and other problems.

@schrodingerscatcuriosity it's working now with Nginx i just want a htaccess (working one). /nl.html exists but if /nl/blog is called there is a directory with /nl/blog.html. So it's not exactly. This file exits /nl/blog.html
